# Microsoft Search Server web service

Tags: .net, web-services, search-server, search-server-2010

I'm a totally new to Microsoft Search Server, and now I need to use MSS in C# to search against HTML files. Now I installed Search Server 2010 Express on Windows Server 2008, but then I'm stuck, don't know how to build asmx web service.. I searched through internet, couldn't find related articles talking about this.

Wish can be helped out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference documentation is located here: [Query Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558894.aspx)

You can find a sample on how to call this WS here: [Example of using the SPServices Search web service](http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/example-of-using-the-spservices-search-web-service/)

Comment: thanks, but I more want how to establish the web service ... the searching scope shall be passed from C# code, cannot be configured in the searching scope tool inside MSS.

Comment: @Elaine - what do you mean by "establish the web service" or "build asmx web service"? You need to "Add a reference" to it using Visual Studio tools for example

Comment: sorry for the confused English.. after researched more, I now know there is /search.asmx (that is what I meant 'establish the web service..), and now I need to do search in location dynamically by c#, I'm still researching. I will update the post description later on.